# Bash command to cat multiple files to be used as a variable

Tags: bash, file, cat

I use an application that has the following syntax:

```
mccli backup delete --name=X --labelnum=X
```

I can manually execute the command each time, which would look like this:

```
mccli backup delete --name=server1 --labelnum=12
mccli backup delete --name=server2 --labelnum=33
```

The problem is that I have 1000 hosts to run this command against. I have a file (name.txt) that has a list of all the `--name=` variables, and a file (labelnum.txt) that has a list of all the `--labelnum=` variables.

I am familiar with the following bash command, which works for one variable (`--name=`), but I can't figure out to make this bash command work with two variables:

```
for i in $(cat name.txt); do mccli backup delete --name=$i ; done
```

This doesn't work:

```
for i in $(cat name.txt) for j in $(cat labelnum.txt); do mccli backup delete --name=$i --labelnum=$j ; done
```

Comment: What do the contents of the files look like?

Comment: The `cat` command con`cat`enates the contents of the input files and writes them to `stdout`. If `for i in $(cat name.txt)` works for you, then `for i in $(cat name1.txt name2.txt)` should also work.

Comment: (Also see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for better ways to read a single file a line at a time in bash)

Comment: I am guessing now, is the first variable coming from file *name.txt* and the second variable coming from the second file *labelnum.txt* ? I am confused, you talk about multiple columns in each files. Best would be if you publish a small part of each file, or simple give more details. I can not give a solution for all possible cases.

Comment: @MaxMuster...You are correct that the first variable is coming from file 'name.txt' and the second variable is coming from 'labelnum.txt'.  I'm trying to get the command to cat 'name.txt' for the first variable (--name=), and 'labelnum.txt' for the second variable (--labelnum=).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you want to get the values for your `--name` and `--labelnum` arguments from the corresponding lines of those two files. Assuming there's no tab characters in the lines of the first file and that the files have the same number of lines:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r name label; do
  mccli backup delete --name="$name" --labelnum="$label"
done < <(paste name.txt labelnum.txt)
```

should do it.

Comment: When I tried that exact syntax, the CLI just showed a >

Comment: @Bryce *Exactly* like that? No changes or alterations? It works fine for me (Using echo because I don't have a mccli program).

Answer (score 1):

cat command understand multiple arguments and file masks, so

```
for i in $(cat name.txt labels.txt); do mccli backup delete --name=$i ; done
```

or even

```
for i in $(cat *.txt); do mccli backup delete --name=$i ; done
```

If the files contains only one argument per line all should be fine.

Comment: I need this command to work for both the --name= variable as well as the --labelnum= variable at the same time. The contents of the "name.txt" file needs to be the variable for --name= and the contents of the "labels.txt" file needs to be the variable for --labelnum=

Comment: To receive better answer, I think it will be better to provide examples of name.txt and labels.txt and expected output/generated commands. Much easier to suggest correct syntax and much harder to create a solution with unclean requirements

Answer (score 0):

You can do a bash script and make two for loops, one for each file. If you really need to use a shell command rather than a shell script then you can make nested for loops.
Such a thing would look kind of like this:

for filename in "name.txt", "labelnum.txt"; do for i in $filename; do mccli backup delete --name=$i ; done done

Comment: Pretty sure OP wants to get the name argument from one file, and the labelnum argument from the corresponding line of the other file.

Comment: Well, he said that he wants to "execute the above command against each file.", so i told him how to do just that

Comment: I suspect `paste` is going to be more appropriate and OP just doesn't know about it.

Comment: Aside from the appropriateness of this answer, there are 2 syntax problems: first, you don't separate items with a comma ($filename will have the literal value `name.txt,`); second `for i in $filename` will simply put the value of $filename into the `$i` variable (unless there are spaces in the filename), it's not iterating over the contents of the file.